# OpenGL: switching polygon mode causes segfault

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault

My computer runs Ubuntu 16.04 with an Intel graphics card. I am using Mesa 11.2 for my OpenGL profile.

My humble OpenGL program displays a simple square in a window. I wanted to make the program toggle in and out of wireframe mode if I pressed a certain key, so I defined the following callback function:

```
void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE and action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_M and action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        // Find the rasterizing mode.
        GLint rastMode;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, &rastMode);

        // Switch modes depending on current rasterizing mode.
        if (rastMode == GL_FILL) {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        }
        else {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, pressing m while my program is running will cause a segfault. Curiously though, on my *other* computer (running Ubuntu 16.04 but with an Nvidia GPU) I have no such issue and the program works as expected.

The problem isn't with `glPolygonMode`: I can place that inside my `main` function and the program will successfully switch modes. The issues seems to lay with `glGetIntegerv`. If I call that function inside my `main` function (say, right outside the game loop), my square will refuse to appear (though there is not segfault).

Here's the complete code:

```
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// Vertex and fragment shader source files.
constexpr char VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE[]   = "simple_vertex.shader";
constexpr char FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE[] = "simple_fragment.shader";

// Window properties.
constexpr int  WINDOW_WIDTH   = 800;
constexpr int  WINDOW_HEIGHT  = 800;
constexpr char WINDOW_TITLE[] = "Triangle";

// Background colour.
constexpr std::array<GLfloat, 4> bgColour { 0.3f, 0.1f, 0.3f, 1.0f };

/*
 * Instructs GLFW to close window if escape key is pressed and to toggle between rasterizing modes
 * if m is pressed.
 */
void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

int main() {
    // Initialize GLFW.
    if (not glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to start GLFW.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Set required OpenGL version.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Create a window object and bind it to the current context.
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_TITLE, nullptr,
                                          nullptr);
    if (not window) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to create GLFW window.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set callback functions.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);

    // Initialize GLEW with experimental features enabled.
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to start GLEW.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Display information on the current GL connection.
    std::cout << "Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Shading Language: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;

    // Define the viewport dimensions.
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, static_cast<GLsizei>(width), static_cast<GLsizei>(height));

    // Create a vertex shader object.
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    // Load the vertex shader source code.
    std::string vertexShaderSource;
    std::ifstream vsfs(VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE);
    if (vsfs.is_open()) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << vsfs.rdbuf();
        vertexShaderSource = ss.str();
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: File " << VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE << " could not be found.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attach the shader source code to the vertex shader object and compile.
    const char *vertexShaderSource_cstr = vertexShaderSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource_cstr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Check if compilation was successful.
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (not success) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Vertex shader compilation failed.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a fragment shader object.
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Load the fragment shader source code.
    std::string fragmentShaderSource;
    std::ifstream fsfs(FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE);
    if (fsfs.is_open()) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << fsfs.rdbuf();
        fragmentShaderSource = ss.str();
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: File " << FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE << " could not be found.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attach the shader source code to the fragment shader object and compile.
    const char *fragmentShaderSource_cstr = fragmentShaderSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource_cstr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Check if compilation was successful.
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (not success) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Fragment shader compilation failed.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Link the vertex and fragment shaders into a shader program.
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);   

    // Check that shader program was successfully linked.
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (not success) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Shader program linking failed.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Delete shader objects.
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // Coordinates of square's vertices.
    std::array<GLfloat, 12> vertices {
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f
    };

    // Indices to draw.
    std::array<GLuint, 6> indices {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    };

    // Create a vertex array object.
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a vertex buffer object.
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    // Create an element buffer object.
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

    // Pass vertex data into currently bound vertex buffer object.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Pass index data into currently bound element buffer object.
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and enable a vertex attribute.
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), static_cast<GLvoid*>(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // It is good practice to unbind the vertex array object, vertex buffer object, and element
    // buffer object.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Set background colour.
    glClearColor(bgColour[0], bgColour[1], bgColour[2], bgColour[3]);

    // Main loop.
    while (not glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // Clear the screen of colours and poll for events.
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Inform OpenGL to use the shader program created above.
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        // Bind the vertex array object and element buffer object.
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

        // Draw the triangle using glDrawElements. The first argument gives the OpenGL primitive to
        // render, the second argument gives the number of vertices to draw, the third gives type
        // used to represent an index, and finally the last argument gives a possible offset in the
        // EBO.
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, static_cast<GLvoid*>(0));

        // Unbind the vertex array object (good practice).
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Swap buffers.
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // Clean up.
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE and action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_M and action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        // Find the rasterizing mode.
        GLint rastMode;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, &rastMode);

        // Switch modes depending on current rasterizing mode.
        if (rastMode == GL_FILL) {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        }
        else {
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While the documentation does not say this. It might be advisable to pass a pointer to a bigger memory location, lets say GLint[2] one for GL_FRONT and one for GL_BACK.

Comment: The documentation *does* say that:  "*params* returns two values: symbolic constants indicating whether front-facing and back-facing polygons are rasterized as points, lines, or filled polygons".

Comment: @mrVoid Your suggestion worked. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Documentation says it:*

> params returns two values: symbolic constants indicating whether front-facing and back-facing polygons are rasterized as points, lines, or filled polygons

Wrapping up @Wyzard and mine comments: `glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, &rastMode);` needs two integers of memory to write to. The segfault was due to writing past `rastMode int`

The solution is to pass a buffer of two integers.

Comment: This is very late to the party, but do you remember which documentation states it? In particular, I have been greeping in the OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification, and cannot match this statement. Moreover, I cannot find any length statement regarding `POLYGON_MODE` (Note: I know that the answer is correct, just trying to get a pointer to the spec).

Comment: https://www.lri.fr/~mbl/ENS/IG2/docs/opengl1.1/glGet.html